# Scrape google trends for keyword from a dropdown and download as csv using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to scrape data for a given keyword at a metro level in google trends. I have gotten so far as entering the keyword that I want into googletrends via selenium, but I just cant find a way to click on a dropdown menu, select an and download it as a csv. I am especially stuck at the dropdown menu part (perhaps I am not able to find out the right class/id).

I have a restriction that this needs to be done as scraper and not via pyTrends API.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://trends.google.com/trends/?geo=US')
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'.//*[@id="input-254"]')
element.send_keys("glass")
element.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
#till this point I am able to enter the word and arrive at the selection page

dropdown1 =driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'_md-select-value').click()   #this is my attempt at clicking on the drop down. However this doesn't seem to work.
```

[image]

I wish to select METRO under the subregion drop down and download the csv using the button next to subregion and store it in a specific path.

Can someone help me with selecting and downloading the csv for a given keyword and region as metro?

Thank you.

Update:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://trends.google.com/trends/?geo=US')
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'.//*[@id="input-254"]')
driver.maximize_window()
keywords = ["glass","wolf","cat","dog"]
for key in keywords: 
#loop through the keywords
    element.send_keys(key)
    element.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
#click on cookie
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".cookieBarButton.cookieBarConsentButton"))).click()
#click on subregion
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[normalize-space(.)='Subregion']"))).click()
#click on metro
    elementbtn=WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//md-option[@value='metro']")))
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", elementbtn)
    #download file
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/md-content/div/div/div[2]/trends-widget/ng-include/widget/div/div/div/widget-actions/div/button[1]/i"))).click()
```

This however only downloads the first element in the list of keywords and then results in an error : Th "Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class_name you have used it is having 23 elements on the page and not unique.
Try unique xpath instead.

Use webdriverwait and wait for element to be clickable.
First click on cookie button and then the respective dropdown

code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://trends.google.com/trends/?geo=US')
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'.//*[@id="input-254"]')
driver.maximize_window()
element.send_keys("glass")
element.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
#click on cookie
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".cookieBarButton.cookieBarConsentButton"))).click()
#click on subregion
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[normalize-space(.)='Subregion']"))).click()
#click on city
elementbtn=WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//md-option[@value='city']")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", elementbtn)
```

### Update

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
keywords = ["glass","wolf","cat","dog"]
for key in keywords: 
#loop through the keywords
    driver.get('https://trends.google.com/trends/?geo=US')
    element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'.//*[@id="input-254"]')
    driver.maximize_window()
    element.send_keys(key)
    element.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
#click on cookie
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".cookieBarButton.cookieBarConsentButton"))).click()
#click on subregion
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[normalize-space(.)='Subregion']"))).click()
#click on metro
    elementbtn=WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//md-option[@value='metro']")))
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", elementbtn)
    #download file
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/md-content/div/div/div[2]/trends-widget/ng-include/widget/div/div/div/widget-actions/div/button[1]/i"))).click()
    time.sleep(2)#slowdown the loop
```

Comment: thank you for the help, is it possible to modify this in such a way that I loop through a list of multiple keywords and download the individual files for each word? for example the first keyword here is "glass", if I had to repeat the same process for say 5 keywords "cat, dog, wolf, bear, sheep' click on the metro and download the csv, how could I make this a repeatable process?

Comment: just create a list keyword like `keywords =['cat','dog', 'wolf']`  and then use `for key in keywords : ` the copy the all code from driver.get() to till end and then only replace the variable `key` in place of "glass".

Comment: hello, thank you for the help so far. I have updated my question with the loop code. I just ran into a problem during the loop. can you please correct me where I am going wrong? I appreciate your help.

Comment: Checkout the update section. you need import `import time`

Comment: I'm getting a time out exception now, I have tried setting the sleep to different values, such as time.sleep(2), time.sleep(5) etc     `88     if time.monotonic() > end_time:
     89         break
---> 90 raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)

TimeoutException: Message: 
Stacktrace:
Backtrace `

Comment: @Jahrakal : to download file try this code instead. `WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//button[contains(.,'file_download')])[2]"))).click()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248860/discussion-between-jahrakal-and-kunduk).

Comment: also the above code doesnt download the metro file, it downloads another file.

Comment: @Jahrakal : I can only guide you, I can't write all scenarios for you. You have started your query with not clicking the dropdown and then started all kind of options. I am sorry!